# cant get dnsmasq to push multiple search prefixes

Tags: dnsmasq

I'm trying to get dnsmasq to push multiple search prefixes to windows machines. If I look in the MS dhcp server, it looks to be using dhcp option 135, but any attempt to configure that eg

```
dhcp-option=135,domain.local1,domain.local2
```

doesnt get pushed at all (I'm using `tcpdump -i br0 -lenx -s 1500 port bootps or port bootpc | dhcpdump` to view wat dnsmasq is sending)

I have minor success using dhcp option 15, but it only pushes a single name into the search prefix as displayed by ipconfig /all on windows

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 4):

Checking the ISC dhcp option list I found this:

```
119     Domain Search   domain-search      
One or more domain names, each enclosed in quotes and separated by commas
```

But note that dnsmasq actually provides you special option (although I'm not sure from which version it starts)

```
dhcp-option=option:domain-search,eng.apple.com,marketing.apple.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Our client machines (Ubuntu 18 server using netplan/systemd-resolve) were not requesting DHCP option 119, but I could solve the problem by forcing the server (dnsmasq) to sentd that option in the reply anyway:

```
dhcp-option-force=option:domain-search,internal,maindomain.com
dhcp-option=option:domain-name,maindomain.com
```

Using the `dhcp-option-force` parameter makes sure that the list is sent to the clients regardless of what they ask for.